# How to pass a char * argument to serial read without getting bad adress error?

Tags: arrays, pointers, serial-port, char

In my main I do the following:

```
int bytesRead=0;
char buf[MAX] = "";
bytesRead = readSerial(buf, MAX);
```

(MAX is defined as 1000)

In the function readSerial(char * buf, int max) the following is done:

```
bytesRead = read(fd, buf, max);
```

Executing my program however gives me the error "bad adress" when doing the read in readSerial. When I did the read like this in the main itself, it worked, but because I have to do more than just read in the readSerial function and because I need to be able to do this readSerial in more than one place in the program, I need to be able to do the read in this function. It shouldn't matter, but the readSerial function is implemented in a separate c file.

Can someone tell me what the problem is please?

Comment: It likely matters **a lot** that it is implemented in a separate c file.  Show the header file containing its prototype which you use to inform main how to properly call it.

Comment: It is in the header file like this:    `int readSerial(char* buf, int max);`

Comment: But I just found a solution, in the readSerial I now do this: `char tempBuf[max]; int bytesRead = read(fd, &tempBuf, max); memmove(buf, tempBuf, bytesRead);` This seems to work, but i don't know if it is a good solution and I would still like to understand why the first way gives "bad adress".

Comment: @ChrisStratton Do you need to see the whole header file?